# Creating new project with Gnome-Builder

Tags: linux, builder, gnome, new-project, gnome-builder

Is it possible creating a **new** project **from zero** using ***Gnome-Builder***?

When I open it, allows me only to load an existing project from my computer or from remote, but I cannot create a new one, but in the official site it is said that it is possible to do it.
Sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"New..." is the first button in the titlebar when gnome-builder is started (on the "Select a project" page). It allows you to create a new project using various templates.

Builder is only a couple of years old: If you are using a very old version this feature may not be in it yet (Anything after 3.21 is definitely fine).

Comment: Thanks, I think it it because in the package-manager the lastest available version is the 3.18.1.

Comment: 3.18 is indeed very old (almost the first stable builder release): there have been three major versions since then.

Comment: Indeed, but it is also the lastest available in the package-manager, and the update manager do not find any update for it.